# using NotificationManager into an android service

Tags: android, service, notificationmanager

I have a service running in the background and I want to notify user if there is a new data, I've used a notificationmanager, and the notification appears, but when clicking on it it doesn't do anything (it is supposed to show an activity
I'm new in android and here is my code

```
NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = newNotification(R.drawable.shoppingcarticon, "Nouvelle notification de ShopAlert", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Intent intent = new Intent(this,GooglemapActivity.class);
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title", "This is the text", activity);
notification.number += 1;
notificationmanager.notify(0, notification);
```

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code. Change Main.Class to your activity class, And Title and content text as you need them.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


int icon = R.drawable.ic_action_search;
CharSequence tickerText = "Pet Parrot";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Hungry!";
CharSequence contentText = "your parrot food meter is: ";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification); // Log.d("test", "Saving Data to File from Service.");
```

Comment: doesn't work neither, thank you for your help but are you sure that this code works even into a service?

Comment: yes this works, Because I copied it from my service. Let me give you complete code and You can use it as you want it. Editing my answer

Comment: How can I send that notification with the message number, that is the badge count?

Answer (score 3):

The following line:

```
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

should look this way:

```
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

since you're trying to start an `Activity`, not a `Service`. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for you help, but it doesn't work too, the notification text doesn't show (in a normal state, when I click I have the notification bar with my notification, but here the notification bar is empty)

Comment: @Yasmine GreenApple, Make sure the code is indeed executed. And by the way the Notification initialization mode you're using is deprecated, take a look at Notification.Builder class as it's the preferred way for constructing notifications now.